# How to show attributes in magento in button form?

Tags: magento

I want to change the style of attributes in a Magento like color and size which shows on a product page in the form of button.
The user can click on those buttons rather than select an option like dropdown.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I see @demongolem edited this.  I am assuming it was his mistake, but are you really looking for **Magenta** like the (pink) color, or an original looking **Magento** color and size?

Comment: @Zak Yeah thanks!  I changed that portion back

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are referring to Color Swatches.  There are several extensions available that can accomplish this for you.

One that I have used personally several times with success is called the Belvg Color Swatch Pro for $59 - http://store.belvg.com/colors-sizes-and-materials-swatch-pro.html

There are several free options out there like the Gala Color Swatch [here](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/gala-color-swatches-free-9787.html).

Searching for "Color Swatch" on [Magento Connect](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/) will get you pointed in the right direction.